# Origin of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in android?

Tags: android, onclick, logcat, indexoutofboundsexception

I made a 5x5 2D array of square buttons, which was defined in a class called organisms, and arranged them them into a game board right to left, top to bottom. When an organism is clicked it changes color (and clicking it again restores its original color). When you click a (different, non organism) button on the side of the array, all of the buttons on the right of those organisms that were already clicked in the array should themselves change color. In the code, this onClick method is called `IterateListener()`.

Here is the problem. I try to do the last part, where I click the button on the side, and the app stops and I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.

`E/AndroidRuntime(893): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5`

I make sure it is referring to an organism in the middle of the array, so the organism to the right should be within bounds. What else would be throwing an arrayIndexOutOfBounds? Let me know if there are any more parts of the code you want to see, but for now I am showing the parts of code that Logcat specifically complained about.

Here is the code for the getRightOrganism:

```
public Organism findRightOrg(Organism org) {
    return Col[org.getRow() + 1][org.getCol()];

}
```

Here is the code for the onClick:

```
public void IterateListener(View v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < colony.getWidth(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < colony.getHeight(); j++) {
            if (colony.getOrg(i, j).isAlive()) {
                colony.findRightOrg(colony.getOrg(i, j)).liveO();
                }
        }
}
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in an array you can iterate only through 0 to `length-1`. So in your `i = colony.getWidth() - 1`, you try to find an element with `row = lenght-1+1 = length`, which is out of bounds for that array.

Comment: It should not be trying to find row = length - 1 + 1 because  findRightOrganism() should only be called for the centermost organism, where the organism to its right is in bounds.

Comment: @DanP ok. How do you make sure it's not a marginal organism, does this check happen in `isAlive()`? In this case mb there's a bug in `isAlive()` logic?

Comment: Well I make sure it is not a marginal organism by choosing an organism that is not marginal- that is what I mean by referring to an organism in the middle of the array. In an array of 5x5 organisms, I click one that is in the third column and the third row. So the right one is well within bounds.This is the isAlive() method:<br/>`public boolean isAlive()
 {
  if(btn.getText().equals("X"))
   return true;
  else
   return false;
 }`<br/> This is the code for clicking an organism:<br/>

Comment: Also sorry about the formatting... I was trying to figure out how to add line breaks and then it timed out on me.

Comment: @DanP just try to abstract away from your app's terms. What I see in your second snippet is that you iterate over a two-dimensional array, and you do it within its bounds. But when `i=4` and `j=0`, you come to following `colony.getOrg(4, 0).isAlive()`. If this org is indeed alive we proceed to: `colony.findRightOrg(colony.getOrg(4, 0))`, which returns `Col[4 + 1][0];`, which does not exist. That's of course if your `Organism.getRow()` returns 0-indexed position as in `Col[][]` array, not 1-indexed, in which case it fails one step earlier.

Comment: That is certainly possible, but again it should not go through that pathway for anything but i = 2 and j = 2, because that is the only organism I activated, and as such the organism to its right, i = 3 j = 2, should be in bounds. However, I may be confused, and as soon as I can get my R.java to build (it randomly pooped out on me), I'll check it out.